# C version of strpos and substr?

Tags: c, string, substring, strpos

I'm really surprised I can't figure out a way to do this effectively. I've tried *strstr*, a combination of things with *sscanf*, and nothing seems to work the way I would expect it to based on my experience in other languages.

I have a char of "**ABCDEFG HIJ K BEGINTheMiddleEND LMNO PQRS**". I do not know where "**BEGINTheMiddleEND**" is in the string, and I would like to end with a char that equals "**TheMiddle**" by finding the occurrences of "**BEGIN**" and "**END**" and grabbing what is in between.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this (find and sub-string)?

Thanks!

-- EDIT BASED ON ANSWERS --

I have tried this:

```
char *searchString = "ABCDEFG HIJ K BEGINTheMiddleEND LMNO PQRS"
char *t1, *t2;
t1 = strstr(searchString, "BEGIN");
t2 = strstr(t1, "END");
```

But something must be wrong from a pointer standpoint as it doesn't work for me. Strstr only takes two arguments, so I'm not sure what you mean by starting at the previous pointer. I'm also not sure how to then use those pointers to substring it, as they are not integer values like strpos returns, but character pointers.

Thanks again.

-- EDIT WITH FINAL CODE --

For anyone else who hits this, the final, working code:

```
char *searchString = "ABCDEFG HIJ K BEGINTheMiddleEND LMNO PQRS"
char *b = strstr(searchString , "BEGIN");
char *e = strstr(b, "END");
int offset = e - b;
b[offset] = 0;
```

Where "b" is now equal to "BEGINTheMiddle". (which as it turns out is what I needed in this case).

Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to realize what a string is. A 0 delimited sequence of chars.

strstr does what it says: it finds the beginning of the given substring.

So calling strstr with the needle "BEGIN" takes you to the position of this substring. The pointer pointing to "BEGIN", advanced by 5 characters is pointing to "TheMiddle" *onward to the next 0 char*. By searching for "END" you can find the end pointer, and then you need to **copy** the substring into a new string array (or cut it, by replacing the "E" with a 0; or implement your own string functions that do not use 0 terminated strings, so they can arbitrarily overlap).

That is probably the step that you are still missing: actually copy the string. E.g. using

```
 t3 = strndup(t1, t2 - t1);
```

Take the string ABCDEF0, where 0 is an actual 0 character. A pointer to the beginning points to the full string, a pointer pointing to the E points to "EF" only. If you want to get a string "AB", you need to either copy that to "AB0", or replace C by 0.

strstr does not do the copying for you. It just finds the position. If you want an index, you can do `int offset = newPosition - oldPosition;`, but if you need to continue searching, it's easier to work with the `newPosition` pointer.

All this is less intuitive than e.g. String operations in Java. Except for truncating strings, it actually is more efficient as far as I know, and if you realize the 0-terminated memory layout, it makes a lot of sense. It's only when you think of strings as arrays that it may seem odd to have a pointer somewhere in the middle, and continue using it like a regular array. That makes "sub = string + offset" the C way of writing "sub = string.substring(offset)".

Comment: Thank you! This led me to this `code`   char *b = strstr(tmpLine, "BEGIN");
   char *e = strstr(b, "END");
   int offset = e - b;
   b[offset] = 0;`code` for which "b" was the string I needed.

Comment: Try `e[0] = 0` to stop at "END". Isn't `b = strstr(..) + strlen("BEGIN")` good, too?

Answer (score 3):

use `strstr()` twice, but the sencond time start from the position returned by the first call to `strstr()` + strlen(BEGIN).

This will be efficient because the first pointer returned from `strstr()` is going to be the beginning of BEGIN, therefore you won't be looking through the whole string again but start at the BEGIN-ing and look for the END from there; which means that at the most you run through the whole string **once**.

Comment: There's no such function as `strpos` in any C standard I'm aware of.  Perhaps you mean `strstr`?

Comment: Edited the question based on this input, unfortunately I'm still not following 100% since strstr doesn't take a "start at" parameter and I still don't understand the pointer aspect to pull the substring. Thanks.

Comment: strstr takes a pointer.. the pointer is the "start at" parameter. and the fact that pointers can point into the middle of what you might call a string, which is an array of chars could help too; but it should've been covered by your C tutorial.

Comment: @Scooter the comment adding that strpos doesn't exist got upvoted too ;)

Comment: btw.. you get strpos if you subtract the original pointer from the one strstr() returns. Question was about C, not php

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle, int offset);
int main()
{
    char *p = "Hello there all y'al, hope that you are all well";
    int pos = strpos(p, "all", 0);
    printf("First all at : %d\n", pos);
    pos = strpos(p, "all", 10);
    printf("Second all at : %d\n", pos);
}


int strpos(char *hay, char *needle, int offset)
{
   char haystack[strlen(hay)];
   strncpy(haystack, hay+offset, strlen(hay)-offset);
   char *p = strstr(haystack, needle);
   if (p)
      return p - haystack+offset;
   return -1;
}
```